# Laravel Plugin development

Tags: laravel, events, vue.js, plugins

I am building a open source application in Laravel and i want other developers to be easily able to build on top of my app without changing core files of my app. So whenever i provide new release/update thier code is not lost.

The best app i know off, which does this beautifully is wordpress. It lets other developers to build themes, plugins on top of wordpress.

Looking at some packages which will support Events & Listeners and dynamic options. My app also uses Vue.JS so this plugin development should support Vue also.

Are there any articles, documentation, ready to use packages with which i can add this functionality into my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are developing for both backend and frontend. To achieve what you are looking for you need to dive into `dependency managers`. Dependency managers allow you to bundle your code into a package and roll out updates easily. Because you will be using semantic versioning, your packages should never break an existing code base(hopefully).

For JavaScript you need:

https://www.npmjs.com/

For PHP you need:

https://getcomposer.org/

I am not going to go in depth here because this topic is way too broad, but this should get you going.